# sort tableViewCells by numbers inside a label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I try to sort the tableViewCells by numbers inside a label, so the cell which includes the highest number in a label should be last, and vice versa.
I tried it with different solutions like following, but it's simply not working, it also doesn't show any error code

I don't know if there is just a small mistake or if it is all completely wrong, but if so, I hope that you know a completely different way to solve it.

TableView:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // download jobs
    jobsRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.jobs.removeAll()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
            let job = Job(snapshot: childSnapshot)
            print(job)
            self.jobs.insert(job, at: 0)
        }
        filterLocation()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

var jobArr = JobTableViewCell.jobDistance!.jobArr
func filterLocation() {
    jobArr.sort() { $0.distance.text > $1.distance.text}
}
```

TableViewCell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!
static var jobDistance: JobTableViewCell?
var jobArr = [JobTableViewCell.jobDistance!.distance.text]

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    JobTableViewCell.jobDistance = self
}
```

Comment: dont be better to sort the data source and then reload the tableView

Comment: I would recommend not sorting the cells, but rather the data source. Let the table view take care of rendering your cells.

Comment: where you call  `filterLocation`

Comment: @Sh_Khan I call it inside viewDidAppear, before the tableview gets reloaded(also updated my question with new code)

Answer (score 0):

lets check out apple doc for the table view https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

as it says there is method:

```
func tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

we can read it like "give me[UITableView] cell[-> UITableViewCell] for this index[cellForRowAt]"

so all we need is just map our data source to tableview indexes:

e.g.

we have datasource array of strings

```
var dataSource = ["String", "Very long string", "Str"]
```

sort...

```
> ["Str", "String", "Very long string"]
```

and then just provide our data to cell (your tableview must conform UITableViewDataSource protocol)

```
// Provide a cell object for each row.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // Fetch a cell of the appropriate type.
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath)

   // Configure the cell’s contents.
   cell.textLabel!.text = dataSource[indexPath]

   return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you sort another array `jobArr`

```
jobArr.sort() { $0.distance.text > $1.distance.text}
```

and append values to another one `jobs`